# Select all items in listbox on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listbox, selectlist

In my MVC application, I am retrieving a list of objects based on an `ID` and stuffing those objects into a Listbox via a SelectList.  Here is what I have:

---

**C#**

```
ViewBag.SpecCatListBox = new SelectList(SelectListMethods.LstChosenSpecCat(incidentVm.ID), "Value", "Text");
```

---

**HTML/Razor**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.LstSpecialCategories, (SelectList)ViewBag.SpecCatListBox, new { id = "SpecialCat-ListBox", @class = "form-control" })
```

On page load, the listbox is filled with the correct options, except that they're not selected.  Is there a way to do this without looping (which is what I've seen in other posts)?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've edited a few things, along with added a line of code.

**C#**

```
ViewBag.SpecCatListBox = new SelectList(SelectListMethods.LstChosenSpecCat(incidentVm.ID), "Value", "Text", SelectListMethods.LstChosenSpecCat(incidentVm.ID));
ViewBag.SpecCatIds = db.TBL_AssocIncidentSpecialCat.Where(x => x.IncidentId == incidentVm.ID)
    .Select(x => x.SpecialCategoriesId).ToList();
```

**HTML/Razor**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.LstSpecialCategories, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.SpecCatListBox, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.SpecCatIds), new { id = "SpecialCat-ListBox", @class = "form-control" })
```

This is selecting all of the options as needed, but is there a way to not use 2 Viewbag objects?

Comment: if `ViewBag.SpecCatListBox` is already a `SelectList` why are you creating a new `SelectList()` and passing it the `ViewBag.SpecCatListBox` as a constructor arg?  I am [not aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist?view=aspnetcore-2.1) of any constructor overload that fits with that.

Comment: @maccettura edited my post, so I guess i can only do this via jQuery?

Comment: I see the edit, but you might want to double check.  It looks like it still wouldnt compile

Comment: @maccettura I'm running it right now.  Works as expected, just not selecting all of the options

Comment: Then the code you have in your IDE is different from what you have posted here.  Look at your Razor line, specifically the number of `)`..

Comment: @maccettura oh sorry, I didn't fully edit the code in the first edit. Now fixed

Comment: @maccettura edited my question with an update.. got it working, but I feel as though there is a better way?

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't use `ViewBag`.  You should always be using a "ViewModel" for each view.  This model will contain all the properties you need for the specific View.  This way you dont have to do any unchecked casting

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this out.

**C#**

```
ViewBag.SpecCatListBox = new MultiSelectList(SelectListMethods.LstChosenSpecCat(incidentVm.ID), "Value", "Text", SelectListMethods.LstChosenSpecCat(incidentVm.ID).Select(x => x.Value));
```

**HTML/Razor**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.LstSpecialCategories, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.SpecCatListBox, new { id = "SpecialCat-ListBox", @class = "form-control" })
```